# FFmpeg doesn't compile with shared libraries

Tags: ffmpeg

I ran the `./configure` script of FFmpeg as follows:

`PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --pkg-config-flags="--static"   --extra-cflags="-fPIC -m64 -I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame   --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --enable-shared`

When I try to compile FFmpeg with `--enable-shared` option as above, I get this error:

`/usr/bin/ld: /home/guel/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.a(common.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/guel/ffmpeg_build/lib/libx264.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I had added `--enable-pic` ,`--extra-ldexeflags=-pie` as well as `-fPIC -m64` to `--extra-cflags` in order to get rid of this relocation error as suggested here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html

But I'm still getting the same error. I need to compile ffmpeg with `--enable-shared` option to interface it with OpenCV, so I have to find a workaround here.

Comment: I had this issue and simply pulling the latest off Github fixed it for me.

Answer (score 19):

I managed to solve the problem. Actually, the additions `-fPIC` and `--enable-pic` should have done the trick, but I stupidly had previously compiled the dependency libraries (libx264 and many others) with `--disable-shared` option because I didn't care about it when I first compiled FFmpeg and just blindly followed the compilation guide here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

After having re-compiled all the libraries with `--enable-shared` option, FFmpeg also compiled with that option successfully.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me immensely. I was running into the same issue for the same reasons.

Comment: Note for `libaom` you need to add: `"-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1"` to the cmake config.